# Flask - Passing POSTGRESQL Rows to HTML

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

So I have been trying out databases, I just wonder why is postgre not displaying the list when I use `fetchall()` and then pass the rows to the rendred html by using `rows=rows`.

Here is my code:

This is my HTML it has a header so I will not include the header only the form to the table:

**admin.html**

```
<form action="{{ url_for('addparameters') }}" class="register" method="POST">
<h1>Add Parameters</h1>
<fieldset class="row1">
  <legend>Nature of Collection
  </legend>         
  <p>               
  <div>                
    Nature of Collection: <br>
    <input type = "text" name = "param1"><br>
  </div>               
  <br>                 
  <div>                 
    Over: <br>          
    <input type = "text" name = "param2"><br>
  </div>               
  <br>                  
  <div>                 
    Not Over: <br>      
    <input type = "text" name = "param3"><br>
  </div>               
  <p>               
</fieldset>     
<fieldset class="row2">
  <div>                  
    Officer-in-charge: <br>
    <input type = "text" name = "officer"><br>
  </div>                
  <div>                 
    <button class="button">Submit &raquo;</button>
  </div>                
</fieldset>     
<fieldset class="row4">----
  <table>
    <thead>-
      <tr>
        <th>Nature of Collection</th>
        <th>Over</th>
        <th>Not Over</th>
        <th>Added by Officer</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for row in rows %}
      <tr>      
        <td>{{row['nature']}}</td>
        <td>{{row['over']}}</td>
        <td> {{ row['notover']}}</td>
        <td>{{row['officer']}}</td>
      </tr>     
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</fieldset>     
</form
```

and here' my python code:

```
@app.route('/parameters')
def addparam():
    if g.user:
        return render_template("admin.html")

    return redirect(url_for('home'))



@app.route('/addparameters',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def addparameters():


   if request.method == 'POST':


         nofcollection = request.form['param1']
         over = request.form['param2']
         nover = request.form['param3']
         officer = request.form['officer']




         ent = EntryP(nofcollection,over,nover,officer)
         add_parameter(ent)
         conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "AF51", user = "postgres", password = "carrotcake092814", host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5432")
         print "Opened database successfully" 
         conn.row_factory = sql.Row
         cur = conn.cursor()
         cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM parameters""")
         rows = cur.fetchall();
         print rows

         return render_template("admin.html", rows=rows)
```

What I want the output to be is that, whenever I add using the form part of the html, the result list gets updated which is also in the same html but is below the form.

Any idea why this is not working?

I actually placed some flags and the list showed in the console when I fetch it all, but it isn't displaying on the website.

when i clearly used

```
rows=rows
```

and looped inside the html

My column names are as what the html contains which are

```
nature, over,notover, and officer
```

Any help is appreciated!I really don't know if its the database or the html. Because it was really showing on my console. The list that was supposed to be passed and to be posted in the same HTML.

Thank you very much for those will answer!

Comment: can't you use sqlalchemy instead of communicating directly with your db?

Comment: It doesn't look like your performing a database commitment.
Also, you have all of this wrapped in a POST request.
That may cause problems